# What should be the style of the tag excerpts on this site?

Tags: discussion, tags

Tags excerpts on this site have a variety of patterns.  The inconsistencies annoy me a little and some are much more helpful than others.

For example, the "For questions about..." prefix on almost every edited tag excerpt is unnecessary and adds no value when the word question already appears in multiple places on the page and there is nothing to tag but questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think tag excerpts such as

> For questions about the Plutus language, a programming language based
> on Haskell.

are better expressed as simply

> A programming language based on Haskell.

Then the excerpt provides genuine value for somebody who hovers their mouse over the tag.

We should definitely follow the guidance in the last few paragraphs of [Redesigned Tags Page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/)